# Is it necessary to specify the database name in the code if the connection to the database is already established?

Tags: python, mysql

Let's say I make a request like:

```
query_select = "SELECT `client_id` FROM `my_databse_name`.`orders` ORDER BY `client_id` DESC"
await cursor.execute(query_select)
```

In this example, I append the database name to the table name (`my_databse_name`.`orders`) instead of just writing `orders`. Is this addition redundant?
Moreover, I've already installed the connection, and when I installed it, I specified the database name - `my_databse_name`.

I even checked if I remove that name and pass it like this:

```
query_select = "SELECT `client_id` FROM `orders` ORDER BY `client_id` DESC"
```

Then my call works correctly anyway. But in a lot of examples, I often see references to tables where the database name is added. Therefore, I'm not sure what should I do and also add. Although I would prefer to remove the database name from my queries.
The question is - does such adding a name affect the reliability of work, etc.?
I am using MySQL.

Comment: *Is this addition redundant?* No until you execute explicit `USE database_name` in each connection before any other operation in it.

Comment: It is unnecessary if there is no common table name in another database or a table with a reserved name.